# Error to create a global Features dataframe from frame-splitted features dataframe

Tags: r, image, image-processing, dataframe

I'm using R and EBImage packages for image processing.
I want a dataframe of cell basic features for each frame, and after, join these dataframes to have only a global one. I'm having issues with the cell number column, I have repeated numbers, or when I'm using another source image, says the number of columns not match. This is an example:

```
library("EBImage")

# Load Image
  nuc <- readImage(system.file("images", "nuclei.tif", package="EBImage"))
# Segmented Image
  nucbw <- bwlabel(nuc > 0.5)
# Create empty dataframe
  data <- data.frame()
# Compute for each frame
  for (i in 1:numberOfFrames(nuc)){
    # Create cell column to identify each cell
      if (i == 1){
        cell <- 1:max(nucbw[,,i])
        } else {
          cell <- (max(nucbw[,,(i-1)]) + 1) : (max(nucbw[,,i]) + max(nucbw[,,(i-1)]))
          }
    # Create frame column to know the frame where each cell belongs
      frame <- rep(paste("Frame", i, sep = ""), max(nucbw[,,i]))
    # Create de features dataframe  
      x <- computeFeatures.basic(nucbw[,,i], nuc[,,i])
    # Binding dataframe for each frame
      comb <- cbind(cell, frame, x)
    # Binding dataframe different frame  
      data <- rbind(data, comb)
     }
data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you only account for the number of objects in the previous frame rather than keeping track of the total number of objects encountered up to the currently processed frame. See the following example for a modification of your original code which should yield the desired result.

```
library("EBImage")

# Load Image
nuc <- readImage(system.file("images", "nuclei.tif", package="EBImage"))
# Segmented Image
nucbw <- bwlabel(nuc > 0.5)
# Create empty dataframe
data <- data.frame()
# Compute for each frame
ntotal <- 0L
for (i in 1:numberOfFrames(nuc)){
  # Create cell column to identify each cell
  nobjects <- max(nucbw[,,i])
  cell <- seq.int(from = ntotal+1L, length.out = nobjects)
  ntotal <- ntotal + nobjects
  # Create frame column to know the frame where each cell belongs
  frame <- rep(paste("Frame", i, sep = ""), nobjects)
  # Create de features dataframe  
  x <- computeFeatures.basic(nucbw[,,i], nuc[,,i])
  # Binding dataframe for each frame
  comb <- cbind(cell, frame, x)
  # Binding dataframe different frame  
  data <- rbind(data, comb)
}

data
```

Comment: Wow!! You are right!! It solved my issue. You are awesome, thanks a lot @aoles

Comment: I have the error "Error: numbers of columns of arguments do not match" when I try to use this code in a shiny app. Everything ok when it's executed out of a shiny environment. I am using images that are reactive. When I want to add the "cell" and "frame" vectors to the computerFeatures, never match. I've tried several ways to merge data but always same error.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the issue could be without seeing it in context. Therefore consider including a reproducible example illustrating it.

Comment: Nop, I was wrong. I had an erratum in a variable name. The code is working as a charm now. Thanks